# SIunitx doesn't show numbers with math font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx

I've installed the siunitx package, but the numbers don't appear with the math font

[image]

[image]

I was using the siunits package before and this didn't happen. But that doesn't have all the features that I need.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead of image of the code fragment please provide complete (compilable) small document, which reproduce your problem. Without it we can't help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Zarko said, without seeing your document is hard to help you: many factors could be causing this. However, try using `\sisetup{detect-all}` after loading `siunitx` and see if anything changes.

Comment: With `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:siunitx}
   m_2 = \dfrac{14,56 - 1,82}{2} = \SI{8,18}{\kilogram}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
` I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: btw, as you can see on the image it might be an idea to use `\num{..}` on all those numbers with comma

Comment: Btw. as it is stated your equation is wrong, there is no unit in the first part, but then it pops up in the second.